# Cast Object[] to another type

Tags: java, reflection, javabeans, cloning

I have class A and class B,  where  class B  requires only 5 of 10 properties from A.

So i have something like,

`A[]  objArray = populateResponse();`

And to cast it into B , i do something like

`for (A : objArray ){
// getters here and  push it to B obj array manually 
}`

Any other suggestions to do it in a better way since A has many fields and size of the array can grow large ?

Thanks  in advance !

Comment: The number of properties of A is irrelevant. Copying 5 fields from an object which has 10 fields takes the same time as copying 5 fields from an object which has 50 fields. The length of the array is also irrelevant: if you need to make that copy, whatever the way you're doing it, it has to be done. I think you're looking for a solution to a non-existent problem.

Comment: Also, this has nothing to do with a cast.

Comment: @JB Thanks for your opinion.  was curious to know whether something could be done .

Answer (score 1):

If B extends or implements A, just cast away.

Otherwise - you can't do that. You will get a [`ClassCastException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassCastException.html).

If the two classes are not related and you still want to do that, you should make them related. Create an interface they will both implement and pass around references to that interface. This will still not allow you to cast A to B, though.

If you're worried about too many instances of A, you can *convert* them to B. Write a function that takes an instance of A and creates an instance of B from it, and lose the A instance.

Comment: That was good catch.  tried it with interfaces and it resulted in exception. could you please elaborate your opinion on extending A in B ?

Comment: You will not be able to case A to B with interfaces, I just suggested you use interfaces if it makes more sense to you.